# Instantiating parameterized classes in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, instantiation

I have an `Operator` abstract class:

```
abstract class Operator[T, U] {
  def setParent(op: Operator[T, U]): Unit

  def newOp(): Operator[Byte, String] = {
    val newOperator = new NewOperator[Byte, String]
    newOperator.setParent(this)
    newOperator
  }
}
```

and another `NewOperator` class

```
class NewOperator[T, U] extends Operator[T, U] {
  var parent: Operator[T,U] = null
  def setParent(op: Operator[T, U]): Unit = {this.parent = op}
}
```

Now, in the second line in `newOp()` method in class `Operator`, I get an error

```
newOperator.setParent(this)
                      ^
```

which says: `Type mismatch: expected: Operator[Byte, String], actual: Operator[T, U]`.

Is the only way to resolve this, is to add `.instanceOf[Operator[Byte, String]]` to `this`?

```
newOperator.setParent(this.instanceOf[Operator[Byte, String]])
```

Comment: Why not use a `trait`? Is there any reason for using an abstract class?

Comment: I see - you have declared the abstract class to be of generic types but restrict the `newOp` to have a very _specific_ type. Why not keep `newOp` to be generic as one of the answers below show?

Comment: @S.R.I: I don't want to do that because of the reason I specified in the comment of Septem's answer.

Comment: The type error is a real error. If you have a different kind of `Operator` and call `newOp` on it, then the `parent` of this new operator will be set to a value of the wrong type and you will get errors at runtime. You need to fix your design so that the types actually line up. What is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

why not make the method `newOp` generic?

```
abstract class Operator[T, U] {
  def setParent(op: Operator[T, U]): Unit

  def newOp(): Operator[T, U] = {
    val newOperator = new NewOperator[T, U]
    newOperator.setParent(this)
    newOperator
  }
}

class NewOperator[T, U] extends Operator[T, U] {
  var parent: Operator[T,U] = null
  def setParent(op: Operator[T, U]): Unit = {this.parent = op}
}

val op = new NewOperator[Byte, String]().newOp
```

Comment: What if, I have yet another operator whose class is defined as `class OldOperator extends Operator[Byte, String]`? In that case I won't be able to do `def oldOp(): Operator[T, U] = ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution restricts all your  Operator[Byte, String] to have Operator[Byte, String] parent type (and you will found it only in runtime if you use `asInstanceOf`).

In general case if parent/child generic type may be different use:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Operator[T, U, P <: Operator[_, _, _]] { 
  var parent: P = null.asInstanceOf[P]
  def setParent(op: P): Unit = {this.parent = op}
  def newOp[TT, UU]() = {
    val newOperator = new Operator[TT, UU, Operator[T, U, P]]()
    newOperator.setParent(this)
    newOperator
   }
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Operator

scala> new Operator[Byte, String, Null]
res19: Operator[Byte,String,Null] = Operator@5470e2f4

scala> res19.newOp[Int, String]
res20: Operator[Int,String,Operator[Byte,String,Null]] = Operator@729c1e43

scala> res20.parent
res21: Operator[Byte,String,Null] = Operator@5470e2f4
```

You may move `newOp` to some subclass and make Operator a trait, if you need to have some specific state/methods for your Operator.

Or you can use type classes for operator specific operations:

```
scala> new Operator[Byte, String, Null]
res23: Operator[Byte,String,Null] = Operator@728b49e2

scala> implicit class ByteOperator(o: Operator[Byte, String, _]) {
     |         def hello = "hello" //here you can access some members of Operator
     |     }
defined class ByteOperator

scala> res23.hello
res24: String = hello
```

If you really need children having same generic as parents:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

class Operator[T, U] {
  var parent: Operator[T, U] = null
  def newInstance: Operator[T, U] = new Operator[T, U]
  def newOp: Operator[T, U] = {
      val newOperator = newInstance
      newOperator.setParent(this)
      newOperator
  }
  def setParent(op:  Operator[T, U]): Unit = {this.parent = op}
}


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class Operator

scala> new Operator[Byte, String]
res15: Operator[Byte,String] = Operator@4e6ea769

scala> res15.newOp
res16: Operator[Byte,String] = Operator@c774157

scala> res16.parent
res17: Operator[Byte,String] = Operator@4e6ea769
```

If you just need to model some AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), case classess may be a good solution:

```
trait Expression[T] {       
     def v: T
}

case class Value[T](v: T) extends Expression[T] 

case class Plus[T1, T2](a: Expression[T1], b: Expression[T2])(implicit wrap: T1 => Arithmetic[T1, T2]) extends Expression[T1] {
    def v = wrap(a.v) ++ b.v
}

abstract class Arithmetic[T1, T2](v: T1) {
     def ++ (v: T2): T1
}

implicit class ArithmeticInt(val v: Int) extends Arithmetic[Int, Int](v) {
     def ++ (v2: Int) = v + v2
} 

implicit class ArithmeticIntDouble(val v: Int) extends Arithmetic[Int, Double](v) {
     def ++ (v2: Double) = (v.toDouble + v2).toInt
} 

scala> Plus(Value(5.0), Value(11.0)).v
res57: Value[Double] = Value(16.0)

scala> Plus(Value(5), Value(11.0)).v
res67: Int = 16

scala> Plus(Value(5), Value(6)).v
res68: Int = 11

scala> Plus(Value(5.0), Value(6)).v
<console>:60: error: No implicit view available from Double => Arithmetic[Double,Int].
              Plus(Value(5.0), Value(6)).v
                  ^
```

Comment: Still learning Scala. Lemme refactor my code, will respond or accept your answer after few hours :).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing like this

```
 newOperator.setParent(this) in abstract class operator you can do something like this

 newOperator.setParent(newOperator)
```

This will solve your problem